# bibliography backreferences with hyperref: format individual page number

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, hyperref, back-referencing

I would like to format the backreferences in italics when the citation is called from a custom command (but not otherwise).
I've been playing with both `\backrefxxx` and `\backrefalt` inside the custom command, but to no avail.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{companion,
  author={Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens},
  title={The \LaTeX{} Companion},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Addison-Wesley},
  isbn={0-201-36299-6},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{ %%% first version I tried
  \let\oldbackrefxxx\backrefxxx
  \renewcommand{\backrefxxx}[3]{\hyperlink{page.##1}{\textit{##1}}}

  \cite{#1}

  \let\backrefxxx\oldbackrefxxx %%%% If I comment this line, all backreferences are in italics; it I uncomment it, all are in normal font 
}

\renewcommand{\mycite}[1]{  %%% second version I tried, same results
  \let\oldbackref\backref
  \let\oldbackrefalt\backrefalt
  \renewcommand*{\backref}{}
  \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{\textit{\ifcase ##1 {}\or {\textit{##2}}\else {\textit{##2}}\fi}}

  \cite{#1}

  %\let\backref\oldbackref
  %\let\backrefalt\oldbackrefalt
}


\begin{document}
\cite{companion}      %% the backreference to page 1 should be in normal font
\newpage
\mycite{companion}    %% the backreference to page 2 should be in italics
\newpage
\cite{companion}      %% the backreference to page 3 should be in normal font again

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

I see that this means that the backreferences are formatted all at the moment they are typeset, not at the moment the citation command is called;
and at the moment of typesetting, each of `\backrefxxx` and `\backrefalt` can have only one definition.

Is there any way to make some items in the list of backreferences have a different style than others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch,expl3}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\mymarkpage{}
\xpatchcmd\Hy@backout{{\thepage}}{{\mymarkpage\thepage}}{}{\fail}
\xpatchcmd\Hy@backout{{\thepage}}{{\mymarkpage\thepage}}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand{\backrefxxx}[3]{
 \tl_if_head_eq_charcode:nNTF {#1}!
  {
    \hyperlink{page.\tl_tail:n{#1}}{{\textit{\tl_tail:n{#1}}}}
  }
  {
    \hyperlink{page.#1}{#1}
  }}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{%%% 
 {{\renewcommand\mymarkpage{!}%
  \cite{#1}}}}


\begin{document}

\cite{companion}      %% the backreference to page 1 should be in normal font
\newpage
\mycite{companion}    %% the backreference to page 2 should be in italics
\newpage
\cite{companion}      %% the backreference to page 3 should be in normal font again


\bibliographystyle{plain}

\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\end{document}
```

[image]